# How to pass a collection of objects as a parameter of a method in java

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have a populated ArrayList collection of objects (students), now I want to pass that populated object into a method signature to write every unique object to a file.

```
    public static ArrayList<PopulateAlumnosObj> populateAlumnos(int idAlumno, String nombreAlumno) {
    ArrayList<PopulateAlumnosObj> alumnosList = new ArrayList<PopulateAlumnosObj>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        mPopulateAlumnosObj = new PopulateAlumnosObj(i, nombreAlumno);     
        mPopulateAlumnosObj.setTelefonoAlumno("5555-5555"+i);
        mPopulateAlumnosObj.setDireccionAlumno("Dirección"+i);
        alumnosList.add(mPopulateAlumnosObj);
    }
    return alumnosList;
}

 *Here I receive the populate objct.*

 ArrayList<PopulateAlumnosObj> mReceiveAlumnosObjList = new  ArrayList<PopulateAlumnosObj>();
    mReceiveAlumnosObjList = populateAlumnos(1, "Isaías");
    writeToFile(mReceiveAlumnosObjList);

  *This does not work!*

  public static void writeToFile(ArrayList<PopulateAlumnosObj> aAlumnoToFile) {
```

now it works!
I was missing this for each!
Thanks anyway.

```
            for (PopulateAlumnosObj eachAlumnoToFile : aAlumnoToFile) {
            pw.println(eachAlumnoToFile.getIdAlumno() + "\t");
            pw.println(eachAlumnoToFile.getNombreAlumno() + "\t\t");
            pw.println(eachAlumnoToFile.getTelefonoAlumno() + "\t\t");
            pw.println(eachAlumnoToFile.getDireccionAlumno() + "\t\t");
        }
```

I'm just practicing with collection and the like;
But I would appreciate your advices. Thanks all of you.

Comment: "This does not work" is not enough information. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: Fill the writeToFile() function with your attempt then let's talk.

Comment: please format your code properly. Makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't instantiate `ArrayList` twice. Leave instantiation inside method `populateAlumnos` only.
2. I don't see your `mPopulateAlumnosObj` declaration. Something like `PopulateAlumnosObj mPopulateAlumnosObj;` must be inside `populateAlumnos`.
3. Passing your `ArrayList` into `writeToFile` method looks correct.

Comment: @IsaíasSosa ok, but your `ArrayList` is still instantiated twice.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this:

```
 List<PopulateAlumnosObj> populateAlumnos = new ArrayList<PopulateAlumnosObj>(100);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            PopulateAlumnosObj mPopulateAlumnosObj = new PopulateAlumnosObj(i, nombreAlumno);
            mPopulateAlumnosObj.setTelefonoAlumno("5555-5555"+i);
            mPopulateAlumnosObj.setDireccionAlumno("Dirección"+i);
            populateAlumnos.add(mPopulateAlumnosObj);
        }

        for(PopulateAlumnosObj student: populateAlumnos) {
            writeToFile(student);
        }

        public void writeToFile(PopulateAlumnosObj alumnos) { //method implementation...
```

But I'm not sure about your `PopulateAlumnosObj` constructor and setters... They look strange...